# OpenID authentication to proxy a site on a blocked port?

Tags: proxy, openid

I'm setting up a service in my office network that I want to expose to only my office mates outside of our network. My idea is to serve it on a port, say 8080, that is not forwarded by our router, but have another service on port 80 that is. The port 80 service should require authentication from Google OpenID and once authenticated would proxy requests to port 8080. Bonus points if you know how to use OpenID with a restriction on domain name as my company has a business domain through Google. Is any of this even possible? Has anyone gotten some subset of what I'm trying to get at working?

I was looking at openid_connect_gateway through rackup and apache's openid mod, and I got forwarding but not real proxying with rackup. Would I be able to get what I'm looking for through apache?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the OAuth module for Apache. See the examples on the page, and just configure using mod_proxy to do the internal proxying of the request. Unfortunately, I'm having to recreate my deployment cause of issues upgrading to apache 2.4. (It should still work, but having some build issues with the OpenID support.)

http://findingscience.com/mod_auth_openid/

There is an example on that page as well for restricting what domain can be used for the authentication. Basically:

```
<Directory />
AuthType                          OpenID
AuthOpenIDSecureCookie on

require valid-user

AuthOpenIDTrusted ^https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud
AuthOpenIDAXRequire email http://openid.net/schema/contact/email @mydomain\.com
AuthOpenIDSingleIdP https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id
AuthOpenIDAXUsername email
AuthOpenIDSecureCookie On
</Directory>

ProxyPass /my_unprotected_site http://localhost:9292/
ProxyPassReverse /my_unprotected_site http://localhost:9292/
```